# I used memory card as adoptable storage in Android Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery, formatting

I used memory card as adoptable storage in Android Marshmallow.And all of a sudden its asking to format the card,but wherein i have my data stored..how do i recover it?thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pc is showing the sd card content. If it is then copy the whole storage into pc and format the card and copy back everything into card.If it is not , then format the card and use data recovery software like diskgetor to get back the lost data.